# Thumbnail generation from video with filestack / filepicker.io

Tags: filepicker.io, filepicker

I have some videos and I want to make just 1 thumbnail by video.

I'm using https://www.filestack.com/docs/video-transformations

I've been looking at the documentation and can't find a way to do that without creating a lot of extra files I don't need.

The files are on S3 any hint, workaround or ideas welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Filestack method for generating thumbnails for a video is by running a transcode video call. What you can do is tell it to only process a small clip, like 5 seconds or less. If you aren't using webhooks, then you can get the results by making the same request again once the file has completed processing, and the second request will send back all the information that would have been included in the webhook.

Please see the section regarding Video webhooks: https://www.filestack.com/docs/video-transformations